# Q# : QDK Errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, q#

I've recently tried to install the `QDK` via the `VSCode` extension in my `Windows 10` Desktop and `VSCode` wasn't able to find the Microsoft libraries even after I was able to execute the code by the `dotnet` run command on the terminal. The code was the sample project code described in the create new project part of the tutorial. I also didn't have `.NET SDK` so I installed it but it seems to be working fine. In computers I got problems all the code, all related to not finding the namespaces.

```
namespace QuantumRNG {
open Microsoft.Quantum.Canon;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Intrinsic;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Measurement;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Math;
open Microsoft.Quantum.Convert;

operation GenerateRandomBit() : Result {
    using (q = Qubit()) {
        H(q);
        return MResetZ(q);
    }
}

operation SampleRandomNumberInRange(max : Int) : Int {
    mutable output = 0;
    repeat {
        mutable bits = new Result[0];
        for (idxBit in 1..BitSizeI(max)) {
            set bits += [GenerateRandomBit()];
        }
        set output = ResultArrayAsInt(bits);
    } until (output <= max);
    return output;
}

@EntryPoint()
operation SampleRandomNumber() : Int {
    let max = 50;
    Message($"Sampling a random number between 0 and {max}: ");
    return SampleRandomNumberInRange(max);
}
}
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the output console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see any error messages in the output console?
To see the output console select "View: Toggle Output" (Ctrl + Shift + U) and select "Q# Language Extension" from the drop down list.
If the drop down list doesn't show "Q# Language Extension" then it probably means that the language-server that gets downloaded on first run is still downloading, so give it a minute or so (depending on your internet connection).

Answer (score 0):

I think I also had the same problem. The .Net SDk which you have downloaded automatically creates a path in the environment variable by the name "%USERPROFILE%.dotnet\tools" so delete this and add "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk" or copy the path of dotnet SDK from the drive where you have installed dotnet and create a new environment variable under user variable. This might solve your namespace problem.